# WAMP: Setting VirtualHosts not working

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost

I have followed instructions on how to set up VirtualHosts for WAMP (Apache 2.4.9) from many websites, even followed the step by step from [forum.wampserver.com](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) with no possitive results whatsoever.

Here's a list of my file modifications:

**Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   local.ruta.com.ar
::1         localhost
::1         local.ruta.com.ar
```

**apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Indexes
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@ruta
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ruta"
    ServerName local.ruta.com.ar
    ServerAlias www.local.ruta.com.ar
    ErrorLog "logs/ruta.log"
    CustomLog "logs/ruta-access.log" common
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/ruta">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Indexes
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know what else to do. Everything seems fine to me, I checked it many many times and I can't make it work. I tried changing the slashes, the quotes in `Directory` and `DocumentRoot`, remove everything but `DocumentRoot`, `ServerName` and `Directory`...

Point me in the right direction please :( Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Ok it does not work???** Please specify what does not work. What is it doing? What is it not doing? Remember we are not clarevoyant and not looking over your sholder.

Comment: Localhost works, phpmyadmin works. If i visit local.ruta.com.at I get error 105 in Chrome. I posted this in wamp forum, you wrote the Sticky, right? There's more detailed info there about OS and apache version

Comment: Can you try another browser, chrome has a few strange issues when running a local web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of troubleshooting together, RiggsFolly was finally able to solve this strange matter.
Long story short, the PC was that attempting a Teredo connection, a transition IPv6 technology, which was failing as it was behind an IPv4 NAT device.

[Solution he found in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/720145/why-does-win7-sp7-64-bit-try-to-resolve-dns-agsint-ipv6-dns-servers) (Thanks Michael Hampton, wherever you are):

> **Why does Win7 SP7 64-bit try to resolve DNS agsint IPv6 DNS Servers?** -
>   Michael Hampton
>   Thus, since Teredo is enabled, your computer thinks it
>   has IPv6 connectivity, when that connectivity is actually broken. (The
>   network status icon uses a completely different check for connectivity
>   that is more accurate.)
>
> To resolve the issue, disable Teredo (and while you're at it, the
>   other two problematic ones, 6to4 and ISATAP). Right-click on Command
>   Prompt and click Run as Administrator, then run the following:

```
netsh int ipv6 isatap set state disabled
netsh int ipv6 6to4 set state disabled
netsh int teredo set state disabled
```

> Then restart your computer.